# Firebase Firestore Time Stamp (how to implement)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

having an issue when trying to document the time of submission (so i can later filter by it) get submitted to firebase.

Let me show what I have at the moment (in a working state)

--

Currently, I have a form where users submit some information, and it gets pushed to firebase. Everything is working (from mnaual input) except for the automatic timestamp I need.

```
export default {
name: 'SubmitResource',

data() {
    return {
        resourceTitle: null,
        featuredImage: null,
        creatorsName: null,
        creatorProfile: null,
        creatorImage: null,
        resourceOriginalLink: null,
        resourceCategory: null,
        resourcePrice: null,
        downloadLink: null,
        resourceDescription: null,
        date: null,
        slug: null,
    }
},

methods: {
    SubmitResource(){
        if (this.resourceTitle){
            this.feedback = null
            //create slug
            this.slug = slugify(this.resourceTitle, {
                replacement: '-',
                remove: /[$*_+-:@"'`~±§?()]/g,
                lower: true
            })

            if (this.resourcePrice == 0) {
            this.resourcePrice = "FREE"
            }


            db.collection('resources').add({

                resourceTitle: this.resourceTitle,
                featuredImage: this.featuredImage,
                creatorsName: this.creatorsName,
                creatorProfile: this.creatorProfile,
                creatorImage: this.creatorImage,
                resourceOriginalLink: this.resourceOriginalLink,
                resourceCategory: this.resourceCategory,
                resourcePrice: this.resourcePrice,
                downloadLink: this.downloadLink,
                resourceDescription: this.resourceDescription,
                date: this.date,
                slug: this.slug

            }).then(() => {
                this.$router.push({ name: 'home'})
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        } else {
            this.feedback = "You must enter a resource title"
        }




    }
}
```

}

For now, I have no implementation for the "Date" to be auto-generated, as it kept breaking my website. But i did mess around with using all sorts of things, especially -

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp())
```

But, maybe I am incorporating it wrong when I try, but nothing seems to work and I often get an error that "Firebase is not defined".

Just incase, the "db import from firebase" looks like this -

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'
var config = {
  apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
  authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
  storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebaseApp.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })
export default firebaseApp.firestore()
```

I have checked here -  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp but still have no clue how to actually input that into my code and have it works, anything I try throws errors.

Thanks!

Comment: You only export the db (firestore) but not firebase to your Component where you call the timestamp

Answer (score 3):

First, importing firebase should be like this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
```

or

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
// import 'firebase/firestore' <- you dont need this
// this is an developing mode, so i would recommend the former one
```

---

Second, You should learn about [import statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

`your-firebase-setting.js`

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
var config = {
  apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
  authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
  storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebaseApp.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })
export default firebaseApp.firestore() // <------ HERE
```

at `HERE`, you are exporting an instance of Firestore, **not an instance of Firebase**,  so you can import it like this :

`SubmitResource.vue`

```
<script>
import firestore from './your-firebase-setting'

export default {
    name: 'SubmitResource'
    // blah blah ...
}
</script>
```

and use it like this:

`firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

---

just in case, if you need both firebase instance and firestore instance, you should do like this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
var config = {
  apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
  authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
  storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebaseApp.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })
export { firebaseApp }
export const firestore = firebaseApp.firestore()
```

now you can import them like this:

```
<script>
import { firebaseApp, firestore } from './your-firebase-setting'
</script>
```

then both of the following code will work:

`firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

`firebaseApp.firestore().FieldValue.serverTimestamp() // <- dont forget ()`

Comment: I would add that you should not do `import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'`, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGqKYpvLkhE

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for such a great answer! 
I see now that it is obvious that it being "undefined" probably meant I wasn't importing firebase properly to my submit page.

However, when I go ahead and use the code example you supplied (for firebase and firestore) my resource array no longer gets filled/no data gets displayed. So now I have opened another can of worms haha.

Wondering, how would I go about actually using firebaseApp.firestore().FieldValue.serverTimestamp() when using my "db.collection('resources').add" to add the new information to firebase?

Comment: IT seems that as I was previously using "import db from '@/firebase/init'" and now am importing by using |import { firebaseApp, firestore } from '@/firebase/init'" I no longer decalre the "db" of db.collection (that starts that process) is that the issue stopping me now?

Comment: @KJParker did you declare `db` variable ? i think you should rename it to `firestore`. `db` is not `firestore`, so it is no wonder you cannot access `db.collection()`.

Comment: see official example: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize . they are substituting `firestore` instance to `db` variable, so they can call `db.collection()`. you did not so, so you cannot call it like that. in this case, you should call `firestore.collection()`

Answer (score 1):

init firebase file

```
var config = {
  apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
  authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
  storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebaseApp.serverTimestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
export default firebaseApp
```

then just call

```
firebaseApp.serverTimestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

Using "firebase": "^9.6.3" and "vue": "^3.2.13"

`import { serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/firestore'`

Usage

`serverTimestamp()`